# Open classes in a module

Tags: ruby, monkeypatching, ruby-1.9.2

I know I can execute the following to add methods to the String class

```
class String
  def do_something
    puts self.size
  end
end

var = "test"
var.do_something
```

and this will return `4`

I want to be able to have a module with a function that takes in a String, but be able to call the `do_something` method on this string (see below for example) - is it possible?

EDIT: Added sample code that is not working

```
module TestModule
  class String
    def do_something
      puts self.size
    end
  end

  def self.test(str)    
    str.do_something
  end
end
```

This gives the error: `undefined method 'do_something' for "hello":String (NoMethodError)`

Comment: Yes. Your code works exactly as written. When you define doSomething in String, it is available on all strings, in all scopes.

Comment: @John Douthat it is not working, I have edited question to show what code im running

Comment: Are you trying to only make Strings have that function inside the scope of your module?

Comment: Ruby doesn't use camelCase, so it should be do_something. Just sayin' :)

Comment: Ruby also uses 2 space indent. Also just sayin'.

Comment: Describe what you are trying to do. Defining `String#doSomething` inside `TestModule` must have some intention. What is that?

Comment: @Dogbert yes this is exactly what I am trying to achieve, @Simon & @Rein Henrichs Thanks! am still learning "the ruby way"

Comment: @Simon: I edited the code. Just doin' it. (TM)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The way your code is written, you're defining a new class called TestModule::String. If you want to modify the built-in Ruby String class, you need to use the fully-qualified name of String (with the ""::") if you want to keep the declaration inside the module.

```
module TestModule
  class ::String
    def do_something
      puts self.size
    end
  end

  def self.test(str)  
    str.do_something
  end
end
```

Adding the "::" tells Ruby that the String class that you want is not part of the TestModule.

It's probably cleaner to just declare String outside of TestModule in the same file.

If you don't want to pollute the global String class, you could just modify the specific String instance that you want to add the method to.

```
module TestModule
  def self.test(str)  
    do_somethingify!(str)
    str.do_something
  end

  def self.do_somethingify!(str)
    unless str.respond_to? :do_something
      str.instance_eval do
        def do_something
          puts size
        end
      end
    end
  end      
end
```

Comment: Should we not be using class_eval? Could you also comment on the performance difference between using instance_eval/class_eval and just modifying global class string? Either way +1 and accepted answer

Comment: It's using instance_eval because you're modifying a specific object, not a class. You could also use `str.define_singleton_method(:do_something) { puts size }`. Modifying the global class will likely perform better. You could use the standard benchmark library to measure the difference.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this?

```
module TestModule
  module_function
  def test(str)
    str.instance_eval{doSomething}
  end
end

Test.test(str)
```

**Edit** Changed due to the change in the question

Just put the definition of `doSomething` outside out the `TestModule` class.

```
class String
  def doSomething
    puts size
  end
end

module TestModule
  module_function
  def test(str)  
    str.doSomething
  end
end
```